# How to define animations for all transitions at one spot?

Tags: android-animation, android-xml, android-architecture-components, android-navigation

I wanna use the same animations for different actions. Is there any way to define them at one spot like a stylesheet?

At the moment my nav_graph.xml looks like this:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/questionnaireFragment"
    android:name="de.fragdichselbst.view.ui.QuestionnaireFragment"
    android:label="fragment_questionnaire"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_questionnaire" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_questionnaireFragment_to_subjectFragment"
        app:destination="@id/subjectFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/subjectFragment"
    android:name="de.fragdichselbst.view.ui.SubjectFragment"
    android:label="fragment_subject"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_subject" >
    <argument
        android:name="questionnaire_id"
        app:argType="integer" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_subjectFragment_to_quizSettingsFragment"
        app:destination="@id/quizSettingsFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_subjectFragment_to_savedQuizFragment"
        app:destination="@id/savedQuizFragment" />
</fragment>
```

As you can see I use the same animations for each action. But what if I have multiple fragments and I wanna change the animations? I would have to change a lot of code lines. So I would like to have one spot where I define the animation for all transitions.

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/NavigationExtensions.kt. They have custom anim here. This is a extension file where google has used it in their sample for navigating between fragments when you select in bottomnavigationview. Does this help?

Comment: Nope, doesn't:( I mean like a style.xml where you define the appearance of all your widgets just for animations.